# URL Redirect Based on Screen Width

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, mobile

What I'm looking for is quite simply, a way to automatically redirect the user to a different URL when the screen or window width is less then 950px.

I don't want to use "refresh" as it's not recommended, and I don't do want to use "User Agent" either as it seams to me less reliable in the long term and I don't want to be concerned with updating this.

This is the Script I see suggested everywhere for this purpose but for some reason it doesn't do anything:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  if (screen.width <= 950) {
    window.location = "https://www.google.com/";
  }
  //-->
</script>
```

I've also tried it with all this variants with no success:

```
window.location
document.location
window.location.href
document.location.href
```

I've also tried placing it as the first thing after Head tag and even before Doctype. Nothing happens...

Comment: Did you try location.href = "your_url"; ?

Comment: Whats the value of screen.width? Sometimes there is a delay on JS? Not ready,..

Comment: @dnmh Yes, I did try document.location.href... Nothing happens.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm answering my own question as I have recently found a more satisfying solution then the one provided by @Finduilas.

This solution not only redirects you in normal circumstances, it will also redirect you back and forth as you resize your window.

Even better! It will redirect you back and forth in mobile devices as you switch from landscape to portrait and vice-versa.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load resize',function(){
        if($(window).width() < 950){
            window.location = "https://www.google.com"
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't work backwards, when I make the screen smaller, it wil go to the window.location adress.
But it doens't go back to the orignal adress

Comment: , unless you use the same script on the other website changing < to >

Comment: Of course you have to use similar script on the other website.

Comment: ```Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined```

Comment: "$ is not defined" means you don't have jQuery.

Comment: I'm currently using the code below on my site to redirect, but it does not automatically redirect interactively (which I love the idea of). 
When I copy and paste the code above however (and only replace the URL), it does not work (I have JQuery). 
Has anyone had success with the code above? 
Is there a syntax issue?     
Here's what I currently use :<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.outerWidth <=900
  ) {
window.location = "put your URL here";
}

Comment: @MamieMcCall I don't know what you're trying to do, the code works just fine as it is. To have the same kind of redirect from the other side (from the mobile version to the desktop version), you have to use the same code there as well. On the Desktop Version you use <950, On the mobile version you use >950. Each version should also have the url of destination obviously.

Answer (score 5):

If you have to use Javascript, try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function redirect() {
   if (screen.width <= 950) {
      window.location = "https://www.google.com/";
   }
```

and in your body add :

```
<body onload="setTimeout('redirect()', 300)">
```

This will redirect the user after 300 ms when the page is loaded, this way you are making sure that the `width` of the screen is available.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did exactly what you suggested but it's not working either.

Answer (score 2):

You can better use JQUERY for this...

```
// Returns width of browser viewport
$( window ).width();
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/width/

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($(window).width() <= 950) {
window.location = "https://www.google.com/";
}
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Website</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If `$(window).width(); ` works, then I dont see why `screen.width` wouldn't work..

Comment: Because you have to load it after $(document).ready()?

Sometimes the JS is faster then the browser, it returns 0 instead of the correct value..

Comment: @Finduilas That doesn't seem to work, but I know nothing of JavaScript, maybe I'm not putting that in the right place, can you provide the full example so I see how to put that in context?

Comment: The example above works fine. You don't get redirected just by shrinking the window which is what I was doing. My mistake. If you, however, refresh the browser after shrinking the window you'll see you do get redirected. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Screen.width is the device's screen size, which is fixed.  Window.outerWidth is the width of the browser window, which can be moved around. I find Window.width to be more helpful, in general.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  if (screen.width <= 950) {
    window.location = "https://www.google.com/";
  }
  //-->
</script>

<!-- you forgot to add window.location.replace("https://www.google.com/"); and yours is a little wrong-->
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  if (screen.width <= 950) {
    window.location.replace("https://www.google.com/");
  }
  //-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
USE THIS ON TOP OF THE HEAD TAG
<script >
  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    if (window.innerWidth <= "Your desired screen width") {
        window.location.href = "redirect loacation"; 
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body >
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers.